# Android Search similar to Facebook's

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar

I would like to build a search similar to facebook's app for Android, this means:

A search bar inside the action bar like this image: [Facebook search](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8291784/IMG_20150429_235834.jpg)

When the user touches the searchbar, the app shows a back arrow, a search field and the a list of suggestions, like this image:[Facebook suggestions before typing](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8291784/IMG_20150429_235857.jpg)

I have already used `searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)` to make the search bar appear always open, but how can I make the back button appear and open a different "page" with some suggestions, instead of the current page (that is a map)?

Sorry that I couldn't post the actual images, just the links, but I'm a beginner and don't have enough reputation yet.

Hope I could explain my question and that someone can give me a help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple sub problems that you need to solve in order to get the behavior you want.

> open a different "page" with some suggestions, instead of the current page (that is a map)?

First off, looks like you need a basic tutorial on [implementing a search interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html).

> but how can I make the back button appear and open a different "page" with some suggestions?

Add a `OnClickListener` to the `SearchView`. When the `SearchView` is clicked, add a regular `Button` to your view hierarchy. Animate the `Button` into view using a property animation.

Do not try and perform animations with ActionBar's existing "Up Button". It is not designed to be animated. You need to add a regular `Button`. And as a result, you need to be able to add custom views into your ActionBar.

You can add custom views into the ActionBar by performing the following  steps

1. disabling android:contentInset inside the styles.xml
2. ActionBar#setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true)
3. ActionBar#setCustomView(customContainerView)
4. Be careful to make sure your custom view doesn't have a width of 0

The `Button` goes inside the `customContainerView`. For simplicity, I would probably put my `SearchView` into `customContainerView` as well so I can easily manage layout weights.